# Cleaner PHP Random Text

Tags: php, jquery, random

Playing around with generating text randomly with each page refresh using php. Is there a cleaner way to approach this? Also, can this be done with jquery?

```
<?php
$random_text = array("Random Text 1",
                "Random Text 2",
                "Random Text 3",
                "Random Text 4",
                "Random Text 5");
srand(time());
$sizeof = count($random_text);
$random = (rand()%$sizeof);
print("$random_text[$random]");
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [array_rand()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
$random_text = array("Random Text 1",
                "Random Text 2",
                "Random Text 3",
                "Random Text 4",
                "Random Text 5");

print_r($random_text[array_rand($random_text)]);
```

Comment: be aware that array_rand returns the key of the array, not the value.

Comment: Yep, should be print_r($random_text[array_rand($random_text)]);